# Connect method in winsock2 does not seem to work

Tags: c++, sockets

```
#define PORT 3000

int sock()
{
    int valread;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    const char* hello = "Hello from client";
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
    send(sock, hello, strlen(hello), 0);
    printf("Hello message sent\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I have this code for the sockets, to be sent at localhost:3000 address. But they are not sent, and Connection failed error pops up. I have node.js server listener socket open at that port.

Comment: What is the error?  Use [`perror`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to get the relevant information.

Comment: @G.M. Error code is 10093 And it says "Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed." I have no idea what it means though xD
I have used GetLastError because I am using windows 10

Comment: Have you called `WSAStartup`?  If so, was the call successful?  Sorry, but the error message seems fairly clear.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows only <sup>1</sup>, you must call [`WSAStartup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) to initialize the Winsock library *before* using any other socket functions, like `connect()`. See [Initializing Winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/initializing-winsock). And you should call [`WSACleanup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsacleanup) when you are done using Winsock.

<sup>1: On non-Windows platforms, there are no equivalent startup/cleanup functions that need to be called when using sockets.</sup>

Try something more like this:

```c
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORT 3000

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsa);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    printf("Winsock initialized\n");

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    ZeroMemory(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket creation failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Connection failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Connection successful\n");

    const char* hello = "Hello from client";

    if (send(sock, hello, strlen(hello), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Hello message sent\n");

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

That said, you really should be using [`getaddrinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) instead of `inet_pton()`, especially if you want to support both IPv4 and IPv6, eg:

```c
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORT "3000"

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsa);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    printf("Winsock initialized\n");

    struct addrinfo hints, *addrs;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", PORT, &hints, &addrs);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("Get Address Info failed: (%d) %s\n", iResult, gai_strerror(iResult));
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;

    for(struct addrinfo *addr = addrs; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next)
    {
        sock = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
        if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            if (connect(sock, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
                break;

            closesocket(sock);
            sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket creation failed/Connection failed\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Connection successful\n");

    const char* hello = "Hello from client";

    if (send(sock, hello, strlen(hello), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Hello message sent\n");

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be sent? But there's no reponse on node.js and in wireshark - https://prnt.sc/ze160d

Comment: @ddd What does your node.js server *expect* you to send? You can't just send it arbitrary data, unless it is acting as an echo server. Otherwise, you have to send it what it wants. For instance, if it is acting as a web server, you have to send it a valid HTTP request. And how do you know it is not responding? This code is not trying to read any response after `send()` is done. As for Wireshark, it can't capture localhost traffic without [additional setup](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

Comment: @ddd You can't use `(PCSTR)3000` with `getaddrinfo()`, it expects real null-terminated strings, so you have to use `"3000"` instead, like I showed in my example

Comment: Node.js code - https://pastebin.com/kapan7RZ
After using "3000", it shows: 
Winsock initialized
Connection successful
Hello message sent

Comment: @ddd I don't see a `"new connection"` message in your server log. Are you sure your client is actually connecting to your node.js server and not to something else? Use [`netstat`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) to verify. I'm not familiar with node.js, but shouldn't `io.on("connection", ...)` be *before* `io.listen()`, per the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-initialization/#Initialization)? Also, the accepted `socket` is waiting for several events, but I don't see your client sending anything that matches those events.